# How can I replace several Data cells with the same cell when they have a equivalent identifying cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

So I am very new to VBA, so I apologize for my terrible coding. I have been searching for several hours to find an answer to this seemingly simple question, and I may have already run across it, but just not understood what it was.

Essentially what I am trying to do is to use an identifying variable to categorize a set of variables. The data I have looks something like the top image in the album, and what I need looks like the second image in the album (except I have over 20,000 points). I would appreciate it very much if anyone could help me.

[image]

[image]

So far I have:

```
Sub Try_3()
SessionID_Cell = Value.Range("D3:D10047")
SessionID_Change = Value.Range("I2:I5748")
Name_Change = Value.Range("J2:J5748")

For Each SessionID_Cell In Range("D2:D10047")

If SessionID_Cell = SessionID_Change Then
SessionID_Cell.Value = Replace(SessionID_Cell, SessionID_Change, Name_Change)
Else
End If

Next SessionID_Cell


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that a macro is a bit of an overkill for this.... Why not use a simple VLOOKUP?

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$C$2:$D$4,2,FALSE)
```

that's for the below example where parameters mean

`B2` is the value to search for

`$C$2:$D$4` is the range of the table to look at

`2` is the column index of the above range for the return value

`FALSE` - exact match

[image]

Comment: Yeah totally overkill. That's what I thought as well. It just happen that I have a code with a logic similar or quite close to it so I can't help but post.

Comment: I see @L42. No worries it's good to have alternative solutions to a problem. I know VBA was involved but the OP may not be aware the solution was a simple VLOOKUP

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim idcs As Range, idc As Range
    Dim rng As Range, idns As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheet1 '~~> Sheet where your data reside, change to suit
        Set idcs = .Range("C2", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rng = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        '~~> pass name id's to array
        idns = Application.Transpose(rng)
    End With

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        '~~> Dump id's and equivalent city on Dictionary
        For Each idc In idcs
            If Not .Exists(idc.value) Then
                .Add idc.Value, idc.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next
        '~~> replace all name id's with equivalent city
        '~~> using the info dumped in the Dictionary
        For i = LBound(idns) To UBound(idns)
            If .Exists(idns(i)) Then idns(i) = .Item(idns(i))
        Next
        '~~> Change this part if you want to dump new data in another sheet
        rng = Application.Transpose(idns)
    End With
End Sub
```

This will substitute all name identifiers with the actual city in place.
It is like find and replace at once with the conditions set at C and D.
If no matching city for the identifier, it will stay as is.
Is this what you're trying?